# Limit of the measure of the delta neighborhood of Borel Sets.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures, fractal-analysis

[Statement 1.7 from Fractal Geometry by Falconer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHAKJ.png)

I am reading through Fractal Geometry Mathematical Foundations and Analysis by Falconer and I am not very familiar with measure theory.

While reading through equation 1.7, I have been stuck trying to figure out if I am just dumb or if the textbook is wrong. $A_\delta$ is the delta neighborhood of a set. I believe that if delta is decreasing, then the Borel sets are also decreasing. I think the true statement is likely $$\lim_{\delta\to 0}\mu\left(A_\delta\right) = \mu\left(\bigcap_{\delta > 0}A_\delta\right) \stackrel{?}{=} \mu(A)$$

Comment: For a set $A$ in some metric space $(X,d)$, presumably $$A_\delta=\bigcup_{y\in A} B(y,\delta),$$ where $$B(y,\delta)=\{x\in X:d(x,y)<\delta\}.$$ Is this the correct definition of $A_\delta$? Do you have the exact definition of $A_\delta$ from the book?

Comment: Under the usual definition of $A_\delta$ (that given in my previous comment), if any $A_\delta$ has finite measure, then $$\lim_{\delta\to 0} \mu(A_\delta)=\mu\bigl(\bigcap_{\delta>0}A_\delta\bigr)=\mu(\overline{A}),$$ where $\overline{A}$ is the closure. It is not necessarily the case that $\mu(\overline{A})=\mu(A)$. Take, for example, $A=\mathbb{Q}$. If $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure, $\mu(\mathbb{Q})=0$ but $\mu(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})=\infty$.

Comment: Its defined as $$A_\delta ={x \in A:|x-y| \leq \delta \text{for some y in A}$$

Comment: Falconer is evidently **not** writing about the $\delta$ neighbourhoods of sets.  He has $A_\delta$ **increasing** as $\delta$ decreases, and he's using $\bigcup$, not $\bigcap$.